# Segmenation fault in file handling operations in C?

Tags: c, file, unix

I'm a newbie to file handling in UNIX, and I can't figure out where and how I'm getting a segmentation fault. Is there any memory that I'm not allocating or is it a problem with the actual opening and reading of the file. Note: There is an empty text file called "hi.txt" in the same directory.

read.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fp;
FILE *wp;

void open(char *name)
{
    char *outname = strcat(name, ".rzip");
    fp = fopen(name, "r");
    wp = fopen(outname, "w");
}

char read()
{
    return getc(fp);
}

void write(char c)
{
    putc(c, wp);
}

void close()
{
    fclose(fp);
}
```

main.c

```
void open(char *);
char read();
void write(char);
void close();

int main()
{
    open("hi.txt");
    write('c');
    close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"hi.txt"` has no space to combine other strings. E.g `open("hi.txt");` --> `char filename[256] = "hi.txt"; open(filename);`

Comment: And Avoid using names like `open`, `read`, `write` and `close`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Hmm, I stilll seem to be getting a seg fault. Also, I'll take your advice and change those function names. EDIT: It's fixed now. What names should I use instead?

Comment: E.g `open` --> `my_open`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLUEPIXY's comment is spot on. You are misusing `strcat` on a character string constant.

To quickly debug segmentation faults in Linux you should use the **core dump** facility provided by the OS.

It is plain simple:

1. Compile with `-g` option

   `$ gcc -o read main.c read.c -g`
2. Remove the limit on core dump file size

   `$ ulimit -c unlimited`
3. Run the program

   `$ ./read
   Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
4. Check that the `core` file has been generated

   `$ ls -l
   -rw------- 1 user01 users 258048 Jun 17 10:30 core
   -rw-r--r-- 1 user01 users    144 Jun 17 10:23 main.c
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 user01 users  14960 Jun 17 10:24 read
   -rw-r--r-- 1 user01 users    300 Jun 17 10:23 read.c`
5. Run gdb on the core file

   `$ gdb ./read ./core
   GNU gdb (GDB; openSUSE Leap 42.2) 7.11.1
   Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   ...
   [New LWP 24468]
   Core was generated by ./read.
   Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
   0  0x000000000040071b in open (name=0x400834 "hi.txt") at read.c:9
   9       char *outname = strcat(name, ".rzip");`

Thus you know the exact line where the segmentation fault occurred.

On modern distributions generating the `core` files became more complicated with the transfer of control over `core` files to `systemd`. Depending on your distribution you might use `coredumpctl` utility to retrieve core files.

Answer (score 0):

Your char *outname does not have enough memory allocated to accomadate the concatenated string.

Use below:

```c
   char *str2 = ".rzip";
char * outname = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(name)+ strlen(str2) );
strcpy(outname, name);
strcat(outname, str2);

fp = fopen(name, "r");
wp = fopen(outname, "w");
```